# Objective-C application crashes with 'unrecognized selector sent '

Tags: objective-c, crash, singleton, selector

I am attempting to create a singleton, which I finally got to build without errors.  I'm missing something, but not sure what.

Here's my console log: [image: (http://imgur.com/ERjIS);] here's my source code: [image: (http://imgur.com/SZKT3)].  Here's the main routine ([image: http://imgur.com/6J5GE]), where it crashes on line 32.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read the warnings you get from Xcode/GCC. They all tell you exactly what you need to do to fix your problem.

Comment: Well, if you're a newbie like myself, it tells only tells you what's wrong, not how to fix it!  Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling twice the sharedDatabaseIntance method?
In your code, it's called sharedSQLiteDB, and it does not need to be called on the object (it won't work as the method is static).

Comment: Overall the right answer, but small nitpick: Objective-C doesn't have static methods, it has class methods. In practice, they tend to be used in somewhat similar ways, but there are some significant differences (most importantly, since class methods are normal methods that happen to belong to a class, they have a concept of `self` and can be overridden)

Comment: I removed line 33 in the main routine, but still getting the error.

Comment: @Spokane-Dude: That's because you're still trying to call the fictitious `sharedDatabaseInstance` method. Like Macmade noted, it looks like the method you want is called `sharedSQLiteDB`.

Comment: Chuck:  YOU'RE THE MAN!  Thank you so much... I have been fighting this for days, and you finally saved my bacon!  Thanks to everybody else too!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a typo. It's `allocWithZone:`, not `allocWitZone:`